# How to read user's current geographical region in Angular2?

Tags: geolocation, angular

I am actually searching for the user's location (at least geographical region) api which can be used easily with Angular2 typescript code.

Comment: Have you checked how to do it in JS? It's the same in Angular ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class CurrentLocationService {

    constructor(private _http: Http) {}

    getCurrentLocation(): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.get('http://ipinfo.io/json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
        .map(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return Observable.throw(error.json());
        });
    }
}
```